# Why & When do we see the lombok files bundled inside the jar?

Tags: java, maven, lombok

We are using maven 3.6.0 to build artifacts for one of our projects with JDK 1.8_331 & lombok version 1.18.2, Eclipse 2019-12 IDE. **mvn clean install -DskipTests** creates jar as artifact as per definition in pom.xml but we can see the extra lombok classes/files getting bundled inside the jar causing deployment issues & increase in size of jar. What could be the issue here ? Thanks!

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lntp.prod</groupId>
    <artifactId>LNTP</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>LNTP</name>
    <description>LNTP Production</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.openspaces</id>
            <url>http://maven-repository.openspaces.org</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <modules>
        <module>LNTPServerModel</module>
        <module>LNTPServerBridge</module>
        <module>LNTPServerSpace</module>
        <module>LNTPServerEntities</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <!-- general -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lntp.version>3.4.0</lntp.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.2</lombok.version>
        <guava.version>20.0</guava.version>

        <!-- maven plugins -->
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.war.version>3.2.2</maven.war.version>
        <maven.assembly.version>3.1.0</maven.assembly.version>

        <!-- spring -->
        <spring.version>5.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- 3d party artefactory -->
        <chardet.version>1.0</chardet.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- apache commons -->
        <commons.logging.version>1.1.3</commons.logging.version>
        <commons.dbcp.version>1.3</commons.dbcp.version>

        <!-- test -->
        <junit.version>4.8.1</junit.version>
        <java.mail.version>1.4.7</java.mail.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3Party -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mozilla.intl</groupId>
            <artifactId>chardet</artifactId>
            <version>${chardet.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lntp.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>lntp-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile,test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>${java.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.assembly.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.war.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information here to help--can't see your pom, don't know if it makes sense that there's both `com` & `org` dirs (or `javax.email`, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton Please take a look at the new image, It would be great to know if is there any way to avoid these files (For Example, Class50.lombok, AUTHORS, changelog.txt, latestchanges.html, etc.) getting bundled inside the jar ? Many Thanks!

Comment: There is probably a Maven plugin configured to add dependencies to the built JAR. Usually, this is either the Maven Assembly Plugin or the Maven Shade Plugin. If you’re still having trouble with it, please include the contents of `pom.xml` in the question.

Comment: @TimMoore Please take a look at the pom.xml attached herewith, kindly ignore the dummy names used for group id, Many Thanks!

Comment: That’s just the parent of a multi-module build, and doesn’t produce a JAR as far as I can see. The problem must be in a child module. It might be helpful to try to reproduce the problem in a simplified example project that only contains the minimal amount of code and configuration needed to trigger this behavior.

Comment: @TimMoore Your hint helped me a lot. There was a problem in Child Module pom file. I just set <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>. It was false previously.